# increase a value in a css class in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a css class to which the layout in html5 and css3 you have enclosed a :hover background-color, this color is stored in the database and pick it up at the controller, now do not know how to make this :hover background-color on-screen display. What I thought is to include html code in the middle of a label  with that style and tell the class that suffers the html tag :hover to increase one, in this way would go picking the value increases

This is kind of my idea in code:

```
<ul class="sub">
      {% for key, c in categorias %}
    <li class="hover">
        <a href="elemento.html">{{ c.nombre }}
            <div class="icon" style="background-color: #{{c.color}}">
                <img src="{{ asset('images/iconoportada/' ~ c.iconoNombre)}}" alt="elemento" />
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
      {% endfor %}
```

each list item has a :hover background different, like the current background catch it from the database, the problem is that I could not capture the: hover css here so I thought Twig

Comment: What do you mean by _increase_ a color? You want it to be darker or lighter?

Comment: no, really do not want to increase the color, but what I thought was the class include you "hover" a value for example to be called "hover1" and that each element will increase that number and the next would be "hover2" in this form it may assign a different color in: hover each element

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. What has to be incremented in the above code? `c.nombre`, `c.color` or `c.iconoNombre`?

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
   {% for key, c in categorias %}
    <li class="hover">
        <a href="elemento.html">{{ c.nombre }}
            <div class="icon" rel="#{{c.color}}">
                <img src="{{ asset('images/iconoportada/' ~ c.iconoNombre)}}" alt="elemento" />
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
   {% endfor %}
```

and Jquery

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      var oldbg = "";
      $(".icon").hover(function(){
         oldbg = $(this).css("background-colod");
         $(this).css("background-colod", $(this).attr("rel"));
      }, function(){ $(this).css("background-colod", oldbg); } );
   }
</script>
```

not tested... just from the top of my head.